# SSRS with a parameter @startdate

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

I currently have an SSRS report that runs daily with the below SQL code as it should. But, when replication goes down and we miss a day, our Court people would like to be able to manually run a missed date by entering a date #1.

I need some help with setting up the parameter @StartDate, that will run the code below.

[image]

I have this SQL:

```
Select *

from Court

WHERE

case_filed_dt =  
CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,getdate())= 2 THEN  
   datediff(day,3,getdate())
  ELSE
   datediff(day,1,getdate()) 
  END

Order by court asc
```

Simple case statement that looks at the date the report is run, if it runs on Monday's, it get Friday's data otherwise previous day's data.

I would like to add a parameter @startdate for my "case_filed_dt" field, to run manually, in case a report is missed.

Example:

If I run for @startdate = '06-06-2022' it will do as my case statement code does, and get data for '06-03-2022'. If I run for @startdate ='06-07-2022', data is for 6-06-2022'.

Thanks,
jer

Comment: I think you want is dateADD() and make the numbers negative

Comment: Create and use a calendar table and this becomes trivial. Such an approach will also support the idea of work days, holidays, and other non work days (e.g., hurricane evacuation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep this simple.

Change your existing dataset query to accept a parameter (`pStartDate`) like this..

```
Select *
from Court
WHERE
case_filed_dt =  
CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, @pStartDate)= 2 THEN  
   datediff(day,3, @pStartDate)
  ELSE
   datediff(day,1, @pStartDate) 
  END
Order by court asc
```

Then in your report, set the parameter's default value to be an expression

```
=Today()
```

Then if the report is run as normal with no parameters passed, it will use `Today()` as the start date or if the report is run manually, any date can be selected by the user.

Comment: Alan, that is it. Thank you for your clear answer. Regards, JER!

Answer (score 0):

a few versions on the fiddle, which should get you started, this one using a variable to simulate the effects of the Case statement.
Change the date and see what happens

```
Declare @DateNow datetime = '2022-06-03'
SELECT @DateNow as YourDate, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateNow) AS DayNow, '',
CASE 
WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @DateNow) = 'Monday' THEN 
   DateAdd(day,-3,@DateNow)
   ELSE
     DateAdd(day,-1,@DateNow)
    END AS ReportDate
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b3ae703d3be9ace930822f7e20230018